# How to merge columns with dynamic number of columns

Tags: python, pandas, append, conda

I am working on an AI project that involves handling a lot of data frames in Python. I am trying to append values to `df`, however, I want to make the number of columns of `df` dynamic depending on the number of columns of the data frame `a`. rowMerge is a function that takes two variables (`a` and `b`). a is a data frame that we provide and b is a data frame that we expect the function to return. This function enables me to merge rows when a has five columns.

```
def rowMerger(a,b):
try:
    b = pd.DataFrame(data=None, columns =[f'Column{i}' for i in range(0, len(a.columns))])
    rule1 = lambda x: x not in ['']
    u = a.loc[a['Column0'].apply(rule1) & a['Column1'].apply(rule1) & a['Column2'].apply(rule1)].index
    findMergerindexs = list(u)
    findMergerindexs.sort()
    a = pd.DataFrame(a)
    if (len(findMergerindexs) > 0):
       for m in range(len(findMergerindexs)):
           if not (m == (len(findMergerindexs)-1)): 
               startLoop = findMergerindexs[m]
               endLoop = findMergerindexs[m+1]
           else:
               startLoop = findMergerindexs[m]
               endLoop = len(a)
           Column0 = ''
           Column1 = ''
           Column2 = ''
           Column3 = ''
           Column4 = ''
           for n in range(startLoop,endLoop):
               Column0 = Column0 + str(a.iloc[n,0])
               Column1 = Column1 + str(a.iloc[n,1])
               Column2 = Column2 + str(a.iloc[n,2])
               Column3 = Column3 + str(a.iloc[n,3])
               Column4 = Column4 + str(a.iloc[n,4])
           b = b.append({'Column0': Column0.strip(), 'Column1': Column1.strip(), 'Column2': Column2.strip(), 'Column3': Column3.strip(), 'Column4': Column4.strip()}, ignore_index=True)
    else:
        print("File is not having a row for merging instances - Please check the file manually for instance - ")
except: 
    print("Error - While merging the rows")
return b
```

I above function is a function I made to merge rows so that I can get rid of the space in between the lines. For example, I have a data frame as shown below.

```
    df=[['7','4','5','7','8'],["","","",'7','4'],['9','4','7','8','4'],["","","",'7','5'],['4','8','5','4','6']]
df=pd.DataFrame(df)
df.columns=[f'Column{i}' for i in range(0, len(df.columns))]



Column0 Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
7       4       5       7       8 
                        7       4
9       4       7       8       4
                        7       5
4       8       5       4       6
```

And the function `rowMerger` removes the space in between the lines and gives me a data frame that looks like below.

```
rowMerger(df,0)
    Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5
    7       4       5       77       84
    9       4       7       87       45
    4       8       5       4         6
```

However, this function is not dynamic. That is, the number of columns of variable `b` is determined manually. Instead, I want to make the number of columns generated inside the function to be dynamic, based on the number of columns of the variable `a`. For instance, if the number of columns of `a` is three, I want to create three columns (`Column0`,`Column0`,`Column0`) and append values to those columns and return a data frame with three columns.

I have tried everything I could but this is something out of my capability. I am still learning python and I would really appreciate it if anyone can help me with this.

Comment: IIUC, u want to remove the spaces in the columns right? that's ur main goal?

Comment: @IIUC, Yes but also merge the rows to the line above. However, I want to consider the number of columns of the input data frame. I want to achieve the same result for different numbers of columns of input df.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function that could help; it works for the example u provided, but u'll have to tweak it to accommodate many other scenarios : The idea is to find the rows that have empty strings, get the columns for those rows, combine them and pass them somehow back to the original dataframe. I put comments in the code; hopefully, they should explain well enuf. Lemme know how it goes. Someone else could possibly have a better one, so just play with it and c.

```
 def process_data(df):

    #convert to string
    #easier to merge rows
    df = df.astype(str)

    #find rows where there are empty strings
    empty_rows_index = df.loc[df.eq('').any(axis=1)].index

    #find columns where there are no empty strings
    non_empty_cols = df.loc[:,df.ne('').all()].columns.tolist()

    #this gets us the index above the rows with empty strings
    empty_rows_pair = [[ind-1,ind] for ind in empty_rows_index]

    #pair index with columns
    rows_cols = [[entry,non_empty_cols] for entry in empty_rows_pair]

    #this combines the columns where empty strings are in the next row
    #with the non empty string row in the previous column
    lump = [df.loc[x,y].sum().astype('int') for x,y in rows_cols]

    #combine and flip, so that the column names are the headers
    merger = pd.concat(lump,axis=1).T

    #to ensure complete reintegration back to the dataframe
    #set the merger index to the previous row index
    merger.index = [i for i,j in empty_rows_pair]

    #drop the empty string rows
    df = df.drop(empty_rows_index)

    #set the rows in df to match with
    #the rows and columns in merger
    #and assign merger to that section
    df.loc[merger.index,merger.columns] = merger

    df = df.astype(int).reset_index(drop=True)
    return df

    process_data(df)

    Column0 Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
0       7      4       5      77     84
1       9      4       7      87     45
2       4      8       5      4      6
```